# 2D array in ng-model angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

I have a problem to saving data in 2D array format. I have a field in mongoose schema with type: Array. Suppose that I have 4 select element in my view. In my view I write ng-model like this:

```
<select id="test1" name="test1" ng-model="test.Hours[0][0]">
<select id="test2" name="test2" ng-model="test.Hours[0][1]">
<select id="test3" name="test3" ng-model="test.Hours[1][0]">
<select id="test4" name="test4" ng-model="test.Hours[1][1]">
```

my problem is that I want to store values like a 2D array but when I save record the result is an array of object for example like this:

```
test:{Hours: [{'0': 123, '1': 345}, {'0': 789, '1': 23423}]
```

but i need something like this:

```
test: {Hours: [[123, 345], [789, 23423]]
```

Could you please tell me how can I save data in 2D array format not an array of object? Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correct, you could have something like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/K8eBi0JElZY76iBrDgne?p=preview)

Comment: Actually I need a two dimensional array. In your plunker you wrote: ng-init="test ={ Hours : [[1], []]}". But I need something like this: ng-init="test ={ Hours : [[1, 2], [267, 22]]}".

Comment: Try this corrected [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/L3g3MhcKZcGbHELAz1EQ?p=preview)

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov . your code works. But I don't want use ng-repeat directive in my code! And I think ng-init just work with ng-repeat as you wrote.